# hiding carousel for small display < 340 x

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel-2

Please, look for a way to hide a carousel script from displaying for screens with dimensions such as : 340x360 . here the script : http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just put the whole thing in an if statement for the screen size.

Comment: need more information

Answer (score 0):

updated:

Use CSS media query

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
   #slider_wrapper {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: hi, tks a lot cyadvert !                                                                                So just  copy and paste will be enough then ?

Comment: Tks in advance...

In fact , i don't knonw exactly if it's :

<div class="slider_wrapper "> or <div id="camera_wrap" class="">

a link may help ...

http://bit.ly/hidecarousel

Comment: Do you mind to mark my answer as useful and correct (arrow up and checkmark)
thank you